# SQL Update subquery returns no results run different sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to do an update and i'm having problems (using microsoft sql server)

```
update mytable
   set myvalue=
   (
       (select myvalue from someothertable
        where someothertable.id=mytable.id)
   )
   from table mytable
   where mytable.custname='test'
```

Basically the subquery could return no results if that does happen i want to call a different subquery:

```
(select myvalue from oldtable
where oldtable.id=mytable.id)
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 0):

well, you could run the second query first, and then, the first query.
In that way, you will override the values only when the first query can bring them, and when the (original) first query won't bring any result, they will have the result of first query.

Also, I think you have a typo in your second query with the table name.

```
update mytable
   set myvalue=
   (
       select myvalue from oldtable
        where oldtable.id=mytable.id
   )
   from table mytable
   where mytable.custname='test'
   and exists (select 1 from oldtable
        where oldtable.id=mytable.id)


update mytable
   set myvalue=
   (
       select myvalue from someothertable
        where someothertable.id=mytable.id
   )
   from table mytable
   where mytable.custname='test'
   and exists ( select 1 from someothertable
        where someothertable.id=mytable.id)
```

edit: you will need to add the exists clause, cause if not it will update with null values, I think

Comment: running second query then the first isn't really an option. I would end up taking a big performance hit because of the size of data

Comment: well but it's the same. Writing as one or as two, you will end up really running two subquerys, what ever you'll do.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join both tables,

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.myValue = b.myValue
FROM    myTable a
        INNER JOIN someOtherTable b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   a.CustName = 'test'
```

Comment: Again the problem with that is the performance hit. In 95% of cases the first sub query returns a result. Thanks for tha answer though.

Comment: do you have indexes define on your tables?

Comment: yes on the ids but in the short term i know I am going to add more sub queries so I can't keep joining!

Comment: Sorry i should add a numm check to the second query